# I need to loop a specific part of a function

Tags: c#

This a follow up to an earlier question got some great feedback and I'm learning, the register works and calculates well. I want to ask is it possible to loop only part of a function, I've inserted an *if* statement that checks to see if the person gave less money than the total and if so would demand more cash. I want to to again demand cash and **after** receiving an amount that is equal or more than the total will carry on and give change. Here is the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public static class Program 
    {
        public static void Main() 
        {



           Console.WriteLine("                    *****--------------------*****");
           Console.WriteLine("                          Wit Groceries 2020");
           Console.WriteLine("                    *****--------------------*****");
           Console.WriteLine("            Welcome, would you like to do some shopping today?");
           Console.WriteLine("");

           var STOCK = new List<Items>
           {
            new Items{ id = 1, Name = "Bun", Price = 150},
            new Items{ id = 2, Name = "Soda", Price = 100},
            new Items{ id = 3, Name = "Cheese", Price =70},
            new Items{ id = 4, Name = "Tissue", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 5, Name = "Fabuloso", Price = 180},
            new Items{ id = 6, Name = "Grace Mackerel", Price = 70},
            new Items{ id = 7, Name = "Rice", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 8, Name = "Flour", Price = 40},
            new Items{ id = 9, Name = "Sugar", Price = 30},
           };



           var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(i=>i.id);

           var selecteditems = new List<Items>();

           STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID {x.id} - Name: {x.Name.PadRight(20)} Price: {string.Format("{0:C2}", x.Price)}"));
           Console.WriteLine();

           Console.WriteLine(" Enter the number for the item you want, enter 'x' when finihshed");


           do
           {
            var choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice.Trim() =="x")
            {
                break;
            }
            int id;
            if (!int.TryParse(choice, out id))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter number or 'x' ");
               continue;
            }
            if (STOCKDict.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                var item = STOCKDict[id];
                selecteditems.Add(item);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " is added to your list");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id + " is not available");
            }
           }
           while (true);

           decimal subt = selecteditems.Sum(i=>i.Price);
           decimal GCT = 16.50m;
           decimal GCTamt = (subt*GCT/100);
           decimal total = subt+GCTamt;
           Console.WriteLine("                  Sub-total = " + "$" + subt);
           Console.WriteLine("                  GCT = " + "$" + GCTamt);
           Console.WriteLine("                  You pay " + "$" +total);
           Console.WriteLine();



           Console.WriteLine("                  Please tender cash");
           decimal tend =decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (tend>total)
            {
           decimal change = tend - total;
           Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $"+tend + " Your change is " + "$"+change);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Please tender more cash");
            }



        }

    }
    public class Items
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public decimal Price {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do a `do while` to achieve that if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Tried the following, doesn't loop `do 
            {
             if (tend<total)
                  {
                  Console.WriteLine("Not enough cash"); 
                  }
                  
                else
                  {
                    decimal change = tend - total;
                    Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $"+tend + " Your change is " + "$"+change);
                  
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    continue;
                  break;
            }
            while(true);`

Comment: @Whitti1 - let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirements it appears that you are only concerns with this part of the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("                  Please tender cash");
   decimal tend =decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (tend>total)
    {
   decimal change = tend - total;
   Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $"+tend + " Your change is " + "$"+change);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Please tender more cash");
    }
```

Where the cash change logic is applied.
If I understand it correctly you can the as following:

```
            decimal total = 15.75m;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("                  Please tender cash");
                decimal tend = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (tend == total)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $" + tend + "the exact amount.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                if (tend > total)
                {
                    decimal change = tend - total;
                    Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $" + tend + " Your change is " + "$" + change);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                total -= tend;
                Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $" + tend);
                Console.WriteLine("         You still own " + " $" + total);
            }
```

In each iteration of the while loop - we request cash - if cash is greater or equal to the amount own - the loop completes and the feedback is provided.
Otherwise we subtract the given amount from the total and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great start, good job;

I think what you need is after you ask to tender cash you can start a do-while loop again, that breaks if the tender >= total while ( tender < total ) but you need these variables to be declared before the loop and you can update them and calculate the remaining ....

Another approach is to wrap each of these in a function and make a switch statement to shift between cases..

If you need more illustration just ask.

Comment: Ok, but how would I structure it? could I keep the current `if` function and encase it withing the loop ?

Comment: Tried the following, doesn't loop `do 
            {
             if (tend<total)
                  {
                  Console.WriteLine("Not enough cash"); 
                  }
                  
                else
                  {
                    decimal change = tend - total;
                    Console.WriteLine("         You gave " + " $"+tend + " Your change is " + "$"+change);
                  
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    continue;
                  break;
            }
            while(true);`